# Trying to convert my JavaScript into JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to convert my Javascript code into JQuery but I know I did something wrong when calling the function. I'm having a tough time knowing exactly what to put when trying to call the radio elements by name.

Original Javascript works, but I'm not sure how to get the JQuery version to work.

Index HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>        
<title>Disney Quiz</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="scripts/quiz.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script
</head>

<body>    
<header><h1>Disney Quiz</h1></header>

<main>

<p>Click on the correct answer for each question and submit your results.</p>

<form>
        <fieldset>
           <legend>Trivia Questions</legend>
           <label> Enter your Name</label> <input type="text" id="myText" name="fieldName" value=""><br>
            <section id="radio1">
                <p> Question 1) What was Walt Disney's first character he created?</p>
                <input type="radio" name="question0" value="A">Oswald the Lucky Rabbit<br>
                <input type="radio" name="question0" value="B">Donald Duck<br>
                <input type="radio" name="question0" value="C">Mickey Mouse<br>
                <input type="radio" name="question0" value="D">Goofy<br>
                <p id="flag0"><p>
            </section>
            <section id="radio2">
                <p> Question 2) Snow White was the first ____ to ever be produced successfully.</p>
                <input type="radio" name="question1" value="A">Movie<br>
                <input type="radio" name="question1" value="B">Live-Action<br>
                <input type="radio" name="question1" value="C">Cel-animated Film<br>
                <input type="radio" name="question1" value="D">Cartoon<br>
                <p id="flag1"><p>
            </section>
            <section id="radio3">
                <p> Question 3) Walt left a big impression when he had created ____ films for the U.S. government</p>
                <input type="radio" name="question2" value="A">Peacemaker<br>
                <input type="radio" name="question2" value="B">Political<br>
                <input type="radio" name="question2" value="C">World War II<br>
                <input type="radio" name="question2" value="D">Religious<br>
                <p id="flag2"><p>
            </section>
            <section id="radio4">
                    <p> Question 4) Which of the following is true?</p>
                <input type="radio" name="question3" value="A">Disney at first wanted to become a filmmaker<br>
                <input type="radio" name="question3" value="B">Disney has made multiple controversial cartoons.<br>
                <input type="radio" name="question3" value="C">Disney holds the record for most individual Oscar wins.<br>
                <input type="radio" name="question3" value="D">Heart failure was the cause of Disney's death.<br>
                <p id="flag3"><p>
            </section>
            <section id="radio5">
                    <p> Question 5) Which of the following has been rumored to happen to Walt Disney after his death?</p>
                <input type="radio" name="question4" value="A">Faked his death<br>
                <input type="radio" name="question4" value="B">Cremated<br>
                <input type="radio" name="question4" value="C">Buried<br>
                <input type="radio" name="question4" value="D">Cryogenically frozen<br>
                <p id="flag4"><p>
            </section>
                 <br>

            <button type="button">Show Results</button>
            <p id="results"></p>
         </fieldset>
       </form>
</main>
<aside>

</aside>
<footer>    <p align="center">  Project 4 - Fall 2018  </p>  </footer>    
</body>
</html>
```

Original JavaScript

```
var answers = ["A","C","B","C","D"], 
    total = answers.length;

function getCheckedValue(radioName)
{
    var radios = document.getElementsByName(radioName);

    for (var y = 0; y < radios.length; y++)
    {
      if(radios[y].checked)
      {
          return radios[y].value; 
      }
    }
}

function getScore()
{
  var score = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < total; i++)
  {
      document.getElementById("flag"+i).innerHTML = "";
      if(getCheckedValue("question"+i) == answers[i])
      {
          score += 1;
      }
      else if(getCheckedValue("question"+i) != answers[i])
      {
          document.getElementById("flag"+i).innerHTML = "Your answer is incorrect.";
      }


  }


  return score;
}

function returnScore()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = x + ", your score is " + getScore() + "/" + total;
}
```

JQuery

```
var answers = ["A","C","B","C","D"], 
    total = answers.length;

$(function getCheckedValue()
{
    var radios = $('[name="question"]');

    for (var y = 0; y < radios.length; y++)
    {
      if(radios[y].checked)
      {
          return radios[y].value; 
      }
    }
});

$(':button').on('click', function getScore()
{
  var score = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < total; i++)
  {
      $("flag"+i).innerHTML = "";
      if(getCheckedValue("question"+i) == answers[i])
      {
          score += 1;
      }
      else if(getCheckedValue("question"+i) != answers[i])
      {
          $("flag"+i).innerHTML = "Your answer is incorrect.";
      }


  }

  return score;
});

$(function returnScore()
{
    var x = $("myText").value;
    $("results").innerHTML = x + ", your score is " + getScore() + "/" + total;
});
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't have innerHTML it uses [html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/). Won't fix all issues but will fix some. Check errors thrown in browser dev tools console also. (F12)

Comment: `$(function getCheckValue()... });` - not sure where you picked up that syntax, but it is incorrect.

Comment: Out of curiosity, just wondering if this is a learning exercise or something different. I just wonder why you want to add ~3200 lines of code (jQuery) to your little app in order to change a few characters and get confused about the syntax.

Comment: It's an exercise. After making our Javascript we have to copy paste everything into another folder, but except this time convert the javascript into jquery form

Comment: Cool. Fix up the two issues. The one I mentioned above is easy. The function  can look exactly like your first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put function definitions inside `$(...)`, just put it at top-level just like in your plain JS version. `$(...)` is for code that needs to run after the DOM is loaded, but you don't need to wait to define functions. It will also call the functions you define there, not just define them.

The jQuery version of `getCheckValue()` isn't using the parameter, you need to add that.

And selectors for IDs need to begin with `#`.

```
function getCheckedValue(radioname)
{
    return $(`[name="${radioname}"]:checked:first`).val();
}
```

In `getScore` your `else if` condition is the opposite of the `if` condition. So you should just use `else`. And jQuery uses the `.html()` and `.text()` functions to fill in an element, you don't assign to `.innerHTML`.

```
$(':button').on('click', function getScore()
{
  var score = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < total; i++)
  {
      $("flag"+i).innerHTML = "";
      if(getCheckedValue("question"+i) == answers[i])
      {
          score += 1;
      }
      else
      {
          $("#flag"+i).text("Your answer is incorrect.");
      }


  }
  return score;
});

function returnScore()
{
    var x = $("#myText").value;
    $("#results").html(x + ", your score is " + getScore() + "/" + total);
}
```

In the HTML, you need to change the order that you load the scripts:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>    
<script src="scripts/quiz.js"></script>
```

Since `quiz.js` uses jQuery, jQuery has to be loaded first.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting an error with f12: $ is not defined

Comment: Did you load the jQuery library?

Comment: You need to put the `<script>` tag that loads jQuery before `quiz.js`.

Comment: I fixed most of the problems, but my results output wont show up. Neither my text errors